# Difference between title and headerTitle in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Probably a stupid question but I can't figure out the difference between the properties `title` and `headerTitle`. I couldn't find anything useful in the documentation.

As far as I can see `headerTitle` will override `title` (e.g. [here](https://snack.expo.io/@javo222/header-title))

Is there a reason to set `title` when `headerTitle` is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`headerTitle` is usually used to provide a **custom header component** ...

```
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{ headerTitle: props => <LogoTitle {...props} /> }}
  />
```

but `title` for changing text-only...

```
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{ title: 'My home' }}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the point. Now I've also realized that if I only define `name` and `component` but omit `option` and everything else, the header still gets the `name` as title. Is that okay to omit the other parameters?

Comment: I'd say you clearly state the `title` of your component in `options` prop ... just to avoid any  not-easy-to-debug issues ... and regrading **omitting other params** ->it depends on your business-needs :)

Comment: perfect. Thanks for the help!